# How to show pandas rows as column after group by

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I want to show rows as column after the group by in pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
df1= pd.read_csv('Employee_Attrition.csv')
df4=df1[['BusinessTravel','JobRole']]
print(df4.head())
df4grouped = df4.groupby('BusinessTravel').count()
print(df4grouped)
jobRolegroped = df4.groupby('JobRole').count()
jobRolegroped
```

I want the output as below

```
**BusinessTravel**     **Sales Representative** **Research Director** ...other category    
Non-Travel                0                           1               ... some number   
Travel_Frequently         2                           3               ... some number
Travel_Rarely             10                          5               ... some number
```

[image: out put]

Comment: Pasting the original dataframe in text would help

Comment: Use `crosstab` here.